Django DRF how do I display not user: 1, but user_id: 1 when sending serialize.data
I came from FastAPI and Laravel and I'm more used to seeing the foreign key id as user_id rather than just user and the like, how can this be done?

Share a [mre] where you are using this and then we can help.

override the funtion in serializer   def to_representation(self, data)
